# Laravel, where do i find the source code for files in the public/js/compiled/ folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am working on a laravel project I received and I find many of the blade files which are in my `resources/views` directory have the following

```
@section('spa-script')
    <script src="{{ asset('js/compiled/app.js') }}"></script>
@endsection
```

I want to work on the layouts but I dont know where the source code is for these files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on the version of Laravel and the compiler you use. For me, the source files (pre-compilation) are located in `/resources/assets/js/`. Alternatively, the final assets could refer to `/public/js/compiled` folder.

Comment: Yes in the /resources/assets/js I have the scripts and in public/js/compiled I have the compiled web pages that the app is serving but  where is the code for the file `/public/js/compiled/app.js` ???

Comment: Hi Jack, 

The key is to figure out how the compilation takes place. Laravel can facilitate several things - look for a gulpfile or a mixfile in the root directory. They often have 'recipes' of which files they compile into app.js.

Comment: Hi Altena thanks that seems to be on to something, the gulpfile says this `elixir((mix) => {
  // mix.copy('public', 'merchant/public');
});` so I checked for a merchant dir its in `resources/views/merchant/public/` and I see there a bunch of .pug files and even in the `resources/views` there are already .pug files, so I guess this pug is some other type of view rendering i dont know about

Answer (score 0):

Generally the `assets()` methods give the path of your `/resources/assets` directory. So any path in this function passed as parameter will added after that. In your case `asset('js/compiled/app.js')` will generate path as `/resources/assets/js/compiled/app.js`.